# How do non-intrusive smart pointers behave with respect to inheritance and multiple inheritance?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11, smart-pointers

I am using C++.  C++0x using Visual Studio 2010 to be correct.

Suppose I have a class Z.  To make it safer in my application to work with pointers to this class, I can consistently use smart pointers (shared pointer, weak pointer).

Now this class Z inherits from a class X.  Some parts of my application will work with pointers to class X, others will work with pointers to class Z.

- Can I still use smart pointers?
- Do shared pointers still work if I have some that refer to X and others that refer to Z?  Is it guaranteed that the destruction of the last shared pointer to the instance (regardless of whether it is `std::shared_ptr<X>` or `std::shared_ptr<Z>`) deletes the instance?  Am I sure that if I delete `std::shared_ptr<X>`, that the instance is kept as long as there is another `std::shared_ptr<Y>`?

Now suppose that I use multiple inheritance, where Z inherits from classes X and Y.
Some parts of my application will work with `std::shared_ptr<X>`, others with `std::shared_ptr<Y>` and others with `std::shared_ptr<Z>`.

- Can I still use shared pointers this way?
- Is it still guaranteed that only the last smart pointer (regardless of whether it points to X, Y or Z) deletes the instance?

By the way, how can I safely cast one smart pointer to another, e.g. cast `std::shared_ptr<Z>` to `std::shared_ptr<X>`?  Does this work?  Is this allowed?

Notice that I explicitly refer to non-intrusive pointers (as the new `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` in C++0x).  When using intrusive pointers (like in Boost), it probably works since the instance itself is responsible for keeping the counter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is supported by the standard, §20.9.11.2.10 [util.smartptr.shared.cast].

The utils you need are:

- `std::static_pointer_cast<>()`
- `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<>()`

They have the same semantics as their C++03 counter parts `static_cast<>()` and `dynamic_cast<>()`.  The one difference being that they only work on `std::shared_ptr`s.  And just to verbose, they do what you expect and correctly share the reference count between the original and newly cast `shared_ptr`s.

```
struct X { virtual ~X(){} };
struct Y : public X {};
struct Z : public X {};

int main()
{
   {
      //C++03
      X* x = new Z;
      Z* z = dynamic_cast<Z*>(x);
      assert(z);
      x = new Y;
      z = dynamic_cast<Z*>(x);
      assert(!z);
      z = static_cast<Z*>(x);
      assert(z); //EVIL!!!
   }

   {
      //C++0x
      std::shared_ptr<X> x{new Z};
      std::shared_ptr<Z> z{std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Z>(x)};
      assert(z);
      x = std::make_shared<Y>();
      z = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Z>(x);
      assert(!z);
      z = std::static_pointer_cast<Z>(x);
      assert(z); //EVIL!!!

      // reference counts work as expected.
      std::shared_ptr<Y> y{std::static_pointer_cast<Y>(x)};
      assert(y);

      std::weak_ptr<Y> w{y};
      assert(w.expired());

      y.reset();
      assert(w.expired());

      x.reset();
      assert(!w.expired());      
   }
   {
      //s'more nice shared_ptr features
      auto z = std::make_shared<X>();
      std::shared_ptr<X> x{z};
      assert( z == x );
      x = z; //assignment also works.
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow never heard of this... O__o No reference to this in any resource I could find on C++0x other than the (indigest) draft...

Comment: I didn't know for sure the casts where there till I looked it up.  I did however strongly suspect they were there as they were part of the original Boost.Smartptr library.

Comment: Please get rid of "std::" in front of the built-in cast operators. Also, a dynamic cast of this type requires polymorphic classes. Your example classes are not polymorphic.

Comment: Fixed it,  Maybe SO should have an option to filter code samples through edge online for validation.